# Find the region of uniform convergence (Weierstrass test)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, self-learning, uniform-convergence

> Find the region of uniform convergence of
>   $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{n^3+x^2n}
> $$

I think that i have to use Weierstrass test but i do not know how to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $n=0$ term is not defined.

Comment: How can i continue?

Comment: Start with $n=1.$

Answer (score 2):

HINT

$$|\frac{\cos{nx}}{n^3+nx^2}| \leq \frac{1}{n^3},\forall x \in \Bbb{R}$$

Comment: Thank you, but what i have to do after this? Could you help me a bit more?

Comment: @piancaStrict use Weierstrass's Theorem

Comment: I can say that the sum from n=0 to infinitive, of 1/n^3 converges, so the sum from o to  infinitive of cosnx/n^3+n^2x converges too..is this enough?

Comment: @piancaStrict just use the weierstrass M-test theorem...it is simple

Comment: i just said what i wrote above...was that enough?

Comment: @piancaStrict not it is not..use explicitly the theorem i mentioned..

Comment: that was the procedure i found from examples in lecture notes..what else do i have to say?

Comment: @piancaStrict.. $\sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}}|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n^3},\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ so by weierstrass M test  the series converges uniformply on $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: i wrote that too..i thought i had to calculate something else..so this is it? thank you very much

Comment: @piancaStrict i insisted because if this question was fr instance an exam question then you have to mention explicitly the theorem you use and how exactly you use it.